# Does Type A Machines Series 1 Pro heated bed have a thermal fuse?

Tags: heated-bed, type-a-machines-series-1

I'm resurrecting a printer I inherited.

Can anyone tell me if the Type A Machines Series 1 Pro heated bed has a thermal fuse in it?

It's a 120 VAC bed and I'd like to protect from a possible short-circuit failure of the SSR. The company is out of business and I haven't been able to find schematics or info on the web.

Below are three pictures of the heat bed. The first is a top view. [image: Top view of TypeA heated build plate]The second is a bottom view.[image: Bottom view of TypeA heated build plate]The third is a back view showing the place where the heater/thermistor cable enters the four-layer heat bed, which comprises (top-to-bottom in this image) an aluminum plate, a gray foam, a reddish layer that appears to be a silicone heater, and a glass plate. (The foam is absent only in this corner where the cable enters the build plate.) [image: Back view of TypeA heated build plate]

Comment: Sounds interesting. A photo of the heated bed, might be useful. A photo of the board could also be useful in identifying any fuse on the board itself. Please [edit] and update your question. FWIW, Type A Machines went out of business on [Jan 2018](https://3dprint.com/205217/untold-story-of-type-a-machines). Have you looked to see if there is a thermal fuse or two attached to the underside of the heated bed? That seems more likely than having an *embedded* thermal fuse.

Comment: I don't know this printer, but seeing as it is quite old, from 2015, I would *guess* that any fuses would be on the main board rather than *integrated* into the heated bed itself (and the heated heat is probably just a PCB). . What makes you think that there is a thermal fuse (embedded) within the board? Just out of interest, do you know of *any* heated beds that have integrated thermal fuses? I'm not aware of any, although there may be as I haven't kept up to date with heated bed technology (since ~2017), so I am probably wrong, and others may know better.